# Как менять значение переменной, после обработки события?

Tags: javascript, html, css, cookie

Есть картинка у которой можно менять перспективу изображения, ещё можно перемещать эту картинку. Так же присутствует возможность заносить данные из JavaScript в Cookie, что по идее должно позволить не сбрасывать координаты в изначальное положение после обновления страницы и благодаря этому управляющие элементы будут сохранять своё положение.
                                               Но есть проблема, я не знаю как правильно организовать внесение изменённых координат управляющих элементов в условие, когда когда куки не пустые(**166 строка js**), что бы координаты управляющих элементов не сбрасывались в изначальную позицию при обновлении страницы.

Подскажите пожалуйста, как правильно организовать внесение изменённых координат управляющих элементов в условие, когда когда куки не пустые?

Заранее очень благодарна за помощь.

Ссылка на пример: http://jsfiddle.net/kbQPW/40/

Comment: Ссылка на `jsfiddle` - это хорошо, но лучше минимальный код, вызывающий затруднения всавлять в вопрос, а ссылку конечно оставить в качестве полного примера.

Comment: В вашем коде запись координат в куки не происходит

Comment: Извиняюсь. Сейчас исправлю вопрос. Не обратила внимание на ошибку.

Answer (score 1):

```
function saveControlPoints(points) {
    setCookie('cPoints', JSON.stringify(points));
}

function getControlPoints() {
 return JSON.parse(getCookie('cPoints'));
}


function initialize() {
  drawSkeletonElement.onchange = redrawImg;
  imgElement.onload = redrawImg;
  controlPoints = getControlPoints() || controlPoints;

  setupDragging();
  redrawImg();
}

  function rectDragDrag(d, i) {
    d.x += d3.event.dx;
    d.y += d3.event.dy;
    d3.select(this).attr('cx', d.x).attr('cy', d.y);
    saveControlPoints(controlPoints);
    redrawImg();
  }
```

Работает: http://jsfiddle.net/upph6edu/10/

Только я бы не стал хранить это в куках, в лучше в localStorage, а также записывать данные стоит в событие onDragOver или подобном, чтобы увеличить производительность